# 'TypeError: undefined is not a function' using Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, protractor, karma-jasmine

I am aware there are many topics on this error code. However, I am struggling to find any solutions that help (or maybe I'm just stupid).

I am building a Protractor test for a web page, and my original JavaScript worked perfectly. But I wanted to convert it all into using page objects, to make it easier to edit and understand as well as avoid code repetition.

The first page object I use for logging in works perfectly fine, however my second page object for adding new users does not.

The main test document from which I am linking the page objects to and from contains both instances of the code that do and don't work, respectively.

- The first instance that works is line 12.
- The second instance that doesn't is on line 23.

  This is shown below:

  ```
    var util = require('util')

    describe ('This is to test the functionality of the Admin page.', function()
    {

        beforeEach(function(){
            browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
            browser.get('https://website');
        });

        it ('Should log in and move to the Users page.', function() {
            var login_page = require('../page/login_page.js');
            var loginPage = new login_page;
            loginPage.login('user', 'pass');

            beforeEach(function () {
                expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('https://website');
            });

            describe('This should hold all the tests while logged in to Admin site', function () {

                it('Should create first new User.', function() {
                    var users_page = require('../page/users_page.js');
                    var usersPage = new login_page;
                    usersPage.addUserButton().click();
                    usersPage.addUser('Test', 'Smith', 'Test100@testing.co.nz', 'Password', 'Password', '0')
                    usersPage.userRole[0];
                    usersPage.confirm().click();
                    usersPage.back().click();
                });

                 it('Should logout', function () {
                    element(by.cssContainingText('span', 'Logout')).element(by.linkText('Logout')).click();
                });
            });
        });
    });
  ```

The error I get when running the Protractor test in cmd is:

```
1) This should hold all the tests while logged in to Admin site Should create first new User.

       Message:
         TypeError: undefined is not a function
       Stacktrace:
         TypeError: undefined is not a function
        at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\\\\\\test
    04_spec.js:25:27)
```

The page that the first instance references is:

```
require ('../page/users_page.js');

var login_page = function(){

    this.username = element(by.id('username'));
    this.password = element(by.id('password'));

    this.get = function(urlVal){
        browser.get(urlVal);
    };

    this.login = function(un, pass){
        this.username.sendKeys(un);
        this.password.sendKeys(pass);
        element(by.tagName('button')).click();
    };
};

module.exports = login_page;
```

And the page that the second instance references is:

```
require ('../page/users_page.js');

var users_page = function(){

    this.addUserButton = element(by.css('[role="button"]'));
    this.firstName = element(by.model('firstname'));
    this.lastName = element(by.model('lastname'));
    this.userName = element(by.model('username'));
    this.password = element(by.model('password'));
    this.confirmPassword = element(by.model('confirmpassword'));
    this.confirm = element(by.css('[class="btn btn-success marginRight10px floatLeft"]'));
    this.back = element(by.css('[class="btn floatLeft"]'));

    this.addUser = function(fn, ln, un, pw, cpw){
        this.firstname.sendKeys(fn);
        this.lastword.sendKeys(ln);
        this.username.sendKeys(un);
        this.password.sendKeys(pw);
        this.confirmpassword.sendKeys(cpw);
    };

    this.userRole = function(index){
        element(by.model('tes.userRole')).$('[value="'+index+'"]').click();
    };

    return require('./users_page.js');

};
module.exports = new users_page();
```

Comment: Note the difference between your use of `module.exports` in `users_page` and `login_page`

Comment: Haha I knew there would be something stupid like that, cheers. Still getting errors, but at least I'm past one hurdle. On to the next thing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
require ('../page/users_page.js');

var login_page = function(){

    this.username = element(by.id('username'));
    this.password = element(by.id('password'));

    this.get = function(urlVal){
        browser.get(urlVal);
    };

    this.login = function(un, pass){
        this.username.sendKeys(un);
        this.password.sendKeys(pass);
        element(by.tagName('button')).click();
    };
};

module.exports = login_page;
```

```js
require ('../page/users_page.js');

var users_page = function(){

    this.addUserButton = element(by.css('[role="button"]'));
    this.firstName = element(by.model('firstname'));
    this.lastName = element(by.model('lastname'));
    this.userName = element(by.model('username'));
    this.password = element(by.model('password'));
    this.confirmPassword = element(by.model('confirmpassword'));
    this.confirm = element(by.css('[class="btn btn-success marginRight10px floatLeft"]'));
    this.back = element(by.css('[class="btn floatLeft"]'));

    this.addUser = function(fn, ln, un, pw, cpw){
        this.firstname.sendKeys(fn);
        this.lastword.sendKeys(ln);
        this.username.sendKeys(un);
        this.password.sendKeys(pw);
        this.confirmpassword.sendKeys(cpw);
    };

    this.userRole = function(index){
        element(by.model('tes.userRole')).$('[value="'+index+'"]').click();
    };

    return require('./users_page.js');

};
module.exports = new users_page();
```

Note the last line of each page:

The working document has no 'new' statement or brackets after the 'module.exports'

Noticed the 'new' part due to Phil's comment, but didn't realise the brackets until just now, so credit to Phil!

Answer (score 1):

There is at least one problem: `addUserButton` is not a function. Replace:

```
usersPage.addUserButton().click();
```

with:

```
usersPage.addUserButton.click();
```

And the same for `confirm` and `back` page object fields.

---

Also, instead of:

```
usersPage.userRole[0];
```

you probably meant to call the underlying page object function:

```
usersPage.userRole(0);
```

---

Aside from that, you probably meant to instantiate a new "users page" object. Replace:

```
var usersPage = new login_page;
```

with:

```
var usersPage = new users_page;
```

Comment: Yeah, I had inserted login_page instead of users_page to humour my debugging interests and forgot to change it back, even with both of your fixes I still haven't resolved the issue and the error I get now is: 'TypeError: object is not a function' and it's on line 23:33

Comment: It is still failing at 'var usersPage = new users_page;' the 'new users_page;' bit

Comment: If you add in 'edit "module.exports" to remove "new" and "()" ' then I will as this was the  true solution, thanks :)