# object is not a constructor Protractor Java Script

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, jasmine-node, jasmine2.0

I keep getting this message saying Newpage is not a constructor i have racked my brains out for the past 5 hours trying to resolve this issue and no progress i have looked at the following sites
[How to call a function in another function in protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33301428/how-to-call-a-function-in-another-function-in-protractor)

['TypeError: undefined is not a function' using Protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28665841/typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-using-protractor)
Maybe it is something simple i don't know. All I am trying to do is call a function form my page object file. Still no success any help would be appreciated.

my code:

```
var newPage = require('./newPage.js');

describe('Get Payroll Information', function() {

  beforeAll(function(){
        var newPageObj = new newPage();
    });

          var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
          var status;
          var clientid, weeknum, pdate;


it('Get CycleStatus, Paydate, Weeknumber, Clientid - completed', function () {
              const fs = require('fs');
              const cycle = $('#cycleStatusID'); // cycle status
              const client = $('#clientID'); // clientid
              const week = $('#companyIdBar_weekId'); // week number
              const payDate = $('#companyIdBar_processDateId');


                //------------Get PayDate --------------------------------
                              .then(() => {
                              payDate.isPresent().then(function(present){
                                if(present){
                                       payDate.getText().then(function(text){
                                         pDate = text;
                                        console.log('paydate (' + pDate + ') is displayed');
                                      });
                                          } else {
                                            console.log('pay date not present');
                                            //return;// breaks for loop like (break)
                                        }
                                      })
                                    })
                                  .then(() => {
                                      writeValueToFile(cycleStatus,clientID,weekNum,pDate);
                                  })
                                  .then(() => {
                                      newPageObj.goBack();
                                      console.log('return to support');
                                  });


                    });// master then promise

              });//spec function
```

Protractor console message 
[image]

newPage.js Code:

```
newPage = function(){
    function goBack(){
      var returnbtn = $('#returnToADPClick');
      var search1 = ($$('input[id="toolbarQuickSearch"]').get(0));
      returnbtn.click();
      browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(search1),20,000);
};
};
module.exports = new newPage();
```

changed to  module.exports = new newPage; // this work now i get
[image]

Comment: what does `newPage.js` export?

Comment: I just added it so you can view. however it is module.exports = new newPage();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `newPage.js` is exporting an object, not a `function/class/constructor`. Change the `module.exports` to just `newPage` like this:

```
newPage = function(){
    function goBack(){
      var returnbtn = $('#returnToADPClick');
      var search1 = ($$('input[id="toolbarQuickSearch"]').get(0));
      returnbtn.click();
      browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(search1),20,000);
};
};
module.exports = newPage;
```

Comment: Okay that worked thanks however when I get to the end of my script to try to execute the function in my page object file i get message "Failed: newPage Object not defined"

Comment: I am trying to execute the function goBack()

Answer (score 1):

> `Failed: newPageObj Object not defined`

This is because of the *scope of the `newPageObj` variable* - currently it is only defined in the scope of `beforeAll`. Declare your variable at the higher level:

```
var newPage = require('./newPage.js');

var newPageObj;

describe('Get Payroll Information', function() {
    beforeAll(function() {
        newPageObj = new newPage();
    });

    // ...
});
```

Comment: Okay that worked however I now get message can not read property goBack of undefined. However as far as i know it is defined  newPageObj.goBack(); from my spec file

Comment: is there anything else i am missing